# Groovy array declaration

Tags: groovy

I'm pretty new to groovy so bear with me but I've got a
bunch of similar code that I'm trying to feed into an 
array. It's pretty straightforward I have my array declaration at
the top and then declaring variables similar to each other below. I only
included three but in reality I have about 10. Except this isn't working 
and I have no ideas why? If anyone has any ideas it is greatly appreciated.

```
def properties = resource.adaptTo(ValueMap.class) ?: [] 
headerText = properties["headerText"] ?: ""
bodyText = properties["bodyText"] ?: "" 
footerText = properties["footerText"] ?: ""
```

Error below:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: headerText for class
```

Comment: It's to include *what* and *how* things aren't working. Are you sure you have an array declaration? Java arrays are indexed by numbers, not strings. Are you instead trying to make an empty map, `[:]`? What's a `ValueMap`? What's `resource.adaptTo`? Does it include mapped property access? Does the property exist? etc.

Comment: I assume you want a map (`[:]`, as Dave said). Other languages (PHP, I'm looking at you) call that an "array" even 'though it's an associative map. And "array" in Java/Groovy is more like a list.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly then my code would be
something similar to: **def properties = resource.adaptTo(ValueMap.class) ?: [:]** ??

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Comment: This question is quite localized (i.e. not likely to help anyone else in the future), so consider generalizing to something like "when/where to use 'def' in Groovy?". That said, please check to see if such a question is already on StackO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm probably missing something, it seems to easy--but:

```
def properties = resource.adaptTo(ValueMap.class) ?: [:] 
def headerText = properties["headerText"] ?: ""
def bodyText = properties["bodyText"] ?: "" 
def footerText = properties["footerText"] ?: ""
```

seems like it should work.

If you are running it as a script (not inside a class) remove ALL the defs--they are required in classes but will break scripts--but if you were running it as a script I would have expected to see it say that "properties" was not defined, not "headerText" so I assume it's part of a class.

Comment: `[]` is a list, so that part, at least, will never work. But IMO the rest is also incorrect; it looks like there just isn't a "headerText" exposed as a property. It's the same error you'd get if you try to access a class property that doesn't exist, e.g., `class Foo { def fname }; f = new Foo(); f["wat"]`

Comment: wow I feel like an idiot it was because I didn't declare **def** thanks for the help!

Comment: Then I take it back :) Except for the list part.

Comment: Changed the list to a map default--should fix that.  Thanks Dave.